# is this sentence gramatically correct? (use of colons followed by semicolons)

Tags: grammar

> It is with economic independence that women become free, for only through this are they: not dependent on men; and capable of acting in pursuit of transcendence.

Answer (score 1):

The colon needs only to be replaced with a semicolon and the semicolon removed.

> It is with economic dependence that women become free; for only through this are they not dependent on men and also capable of acting in pursuit of transcendence.

Answer (score 1):

How about swap comma for semicolon:

> It is with economic independence that women become free, for only through this are they: not dependent on men, and capable of acting in pursuit of transcendence.

I don't grok the need utility of a semicolon..?  As @socrates almost said (I get ya!), they're not *mutually-exclusive* – i.e., "either-or-not-both" – they are *orthogonal* concepts, separate and capable of being attained independently and thus listwise-enumerable following a colon.